# PhoneGap Android LowLatencyAudio plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, audio, plugins, phonegap-plugins

I'm building a mobile game with HTML5 and Javascript, for Android devices.

Android doesn't support HTML5 Audio, that's why i've choose to use a phonegap plugin : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LowLatencyAudio

My structure is very simple, i've got 3 objects.

- game, which is my main object.
- animation, which is my object where are all my sprites animations.
- sound, which all my sound are played, looped or stopped.

Here, my index.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="PGLowLatencyAudio.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="assets/js/src/pixi.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="assets/js/game.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="assets/js/sound.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="assets/js/animation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
        function onDeviceReady(){
            PGLowLatencyAudio.preloadFX('drum','assets/son/drum/drumPiste1.mp3', game.sound.successHandler, game.sound.errorHandler);
        };
        function onBodyLoad(){
            document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
    <div id="wrapper"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
        game.init();
        game.sound.init();
        game.animation.init();
    </script>
</body>
```

I'm using the `PGLowLatencyAudio.preloadFX` function of the plugin, to preload my mp3 file.

After, I call my `init` function of my object sound, which is like that :

```
game.sound = {

    init: function(){
        soundsArray = [];
        game.sound.playSound();
    },

    successHandler: function(result){
        alert(result);
    },

    errorHandler: function(error){
        alert(error);
    },

    playSound: function(){
        PGLowLatencyAudio.play('drum', game.sound.successHandler, game.sound.errorHandler);
    },

};
```

In my `init` function, i call my `playSound` function, to play the sound i've previously preload.

It try to play sound before preload, but i don't understand why.

Error message is : `A reference does not exist for the specified audio id`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [link](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/01/25/low-latency-polyphonic-audio-in-phonegap/), which i followed for a similar project earlier.
It has the solution to the problem !

Comment: That's great, my problem is resolved. Thank's for answer.
But now, i've got another problem.
I can't preload sound with the `preloadAudio` function, it doesn't work. I can just do it with the `preloadFX` function.

Comment: @Lilrom - the link i gave you has the solution to that too.